# Prove that: $\|f\|$ is constant in $G$.

Tags: complex-analysis, normed-spaces, connectedness, holomorphic-bundles

Suppose $G$ is a connected open set of $E$ and $f \in \mathcal{H}(G,F)= \{f: G \to F$, $f$ $\text{is holomorphic mapping} \}$.

Suppose there is a points $a \in G$, such that $\|f(x)\| \le \|f(a)\|$, $\forall x \in G$.

Prove that: $\|f\|$ is constant in $G$.

---

I have some ideas:

Let $A=\{x \in G: \|f(x)\|=\|f(a)\|\}$, we'll show that $A=G$.

(1). We have $A \ne \emptyset$, since $a \in A$ .

(2). We will show that $A$ is **closed**.

Which means $\{x_n\} \subset A, x_n \to x$ then $x\in A$ .

Because $f$ is holomorphic in $G$, hence $\|f(x)\|=\lim_{n \to \infty}\|f(x_n)\|=\|f(a)\| \implies x \in A$.

(3). We will show that $A$ be ***open*** set.

In this situation I'm having trouble.
Any help (or hint or another solution) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where $E$ and $F$ are two _complex Banach spaces_. **BenjaLim**!

Comment: This is achieved by the maximum modules principle states that if f is a holomorphic function, then the modulus $|f|$ cannot exhibit a true local maximum that is properly within the domain of f.

Comment: Are you sure?  you mean $f$ is constant? We use **the maximum modules principle** if $f \in \mathcal{H}(U)=\mathcal{H}(U,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Think of the expression $f(x)=f(a)+$power series.

Comment: What? Can you write it? **Averroes**! :)

Answer (score 0):

(3). We will show that A be **open** set.

$\forall x_0 \in A$, We choose $r>0$ such that $\overline{B}(x_0,r) \subset G$.

With $t \in E,\left \|t  \right \|<r$ then:
$x_0 +\xi t \in \overline{B}(x_0,r)\subset G,~~ \forall \left | \xi \right |=1$.

We now apply **Cauchy's integral formula**:

$f(x_0)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\left | \xi \right |=1}\frac{f(x_0+\xi t)}{\xi}\mathrm{d}\xi \implies \left \| f(x_0) \right \|=\frac{1}{2 \pi }\int_{\left | \xi \right |=1} \left \| \frac{f(x_0+\xi t)}{\xi}\mathrm{d}\xi \right \| \le \left \| f(a) \right \|.$

We have $\left \| f(x_0+\xi t) \right \|=\left \| f(a) \right \|,~~ \forall \left | \xi \right |=1$.

In particular,$\left \| f(x_0+t) \right \|=\left \| f(a) \right \|$

$\implies \left \| f(x) \right \|=\left \| f(x_0+t) \right \|=\left \| f(a) \right \|, \forall x=x_0+t \in B(x_0,r)$.

$\implies B(x_0,r) \subset A$.

Hence, $\emptyset \ne A$, $A$ is closed and open in a connected open set $G$.

Therefore, $A=G$. :p

Comment: when I commented first I wanted you to prove Cauchy's integral formula (that you happen to know as I see) :) actually you have to apply it to f at $x=a$ instead of a random $x_0$ (you did it in the opposite sense which does not lead to the right conclusion

Comment: Are you sure? you mean i'm wrong??? No! No!  I'm right :) Can you post your solution? (To prove that you have true solution for my problem) You can? I'll sit here, next to the computer and wait for your answer. Okay! ;)

Comment: you should have written $f(a)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\left | \xi \right |=1}\frac{f(a +\xi t)}{\xi}\mathrm{d}\xi \implies \left \| f(a) \right \|=\frac{1}{2 \pi }\int_{\left | \xi \right |=1} \left \| \frac{f(a+\xi t)}{\xi}\mathrm{d}\xi \right \| \lneqq  \left \| f(a) \right \|.$

Comment: That would contradict the constance assumption

Comment: Oh, no! ! I feel it seems you misunderstood what I wrote. :(  Applying **Cauchy's integral formula**: $f(x_0+\lambda t)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\left | \xi \right |=1}\frac{f(x_0 +\xi t)}{\xi}\mathrm{d}\xi$, (taking $\lambda =0$) $\implies \left \| f(x_0) \right \|=\frac{1}{2 \pi }\int_{\left | \xi \right |=1} \left \| \frac{f(x_0+\xi t)}{\xi}\mathrm{d}\xi \right \| \le \frac{1}{2 \pi }\int_{\left | \xi \right |=1}  \frac{\left \|f(x_0+\xi t)\right \|}{|\xi|}|\mathrm{d}\xi|  \le ||f(a)||$

Comment: Since $|ξ|=1$; $\int_{|ξ|=1}|\mathrm{d}ξ|=2\pi$ and $\|f(x)\| \le \|f(a)\|$ then $\|f(x_0)\| \le \|f(a)\|$.